# Which one to teach first: solfege or absolute notation?

Tags: theory, sheet-music

Which musical notation should be taught to kids first- the solfege (movable do, in this case) or absolute notation?

Comment: I'm not sure who voted to close. I don't have time to answer this right now, but this is an INCREDIBLY well researched subject and is not subject to opinion.

Comment: There is no reason why a child cannot be taught to read notes from a young age,.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes  citations, please?  I'm highly skeptical, since children learn in many different ways, and what's optimal for one is not at all applicable to the next child.  FWIW,  I see no reason not to teach both in parallel.  Often the best way to learn something is from multiple approaches.

Comment: Even as a kid, I didn't enjoy singing but was more interested in reading sheet music. Solfege is only really applicable to singing, so it's not going to apply to what all your students will end up wanting to do with music, but arguably learning absolute notation doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that culture may come in here. In some countries, the solfege system is thought of as quite important. In France, for example, it's a fixed doh at C, and all the notes are named from this. So there, it would be useful. In England, there's not so much emphasis, so learning dots  makes more sense. No doubt, other countries will have their own views, so the solution will vary. Best to go with the flow.

The fixed doh is not easy to sing with # and b. The movable doh will give some sense of key and intervals, but the stave is universal. For a child beginner it's pretty boring, though.